# Constant String is changing on call

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a class Konst for all the constants in my project. One of the constants acquires the system property user.home. When I call the constant in a different class it has a different outcome as in the constant class.

```java
public final class Konst {

  public static final String SERVER = "Server"; 
  public static final String LOGIN = "Login";
  public static final String CHAT = "Chat";
  public static final String PATH = System.getProperty("user.home");
}
```

```java
public final class ConfigLoader {

  private static final String CONFIG_PATH = Konst.PATH + "/Documents/config.xml";

  private static final Logger LOG = ChatManager.getLogger();

  private ConfigLoader() {
  }

...
}
```

The value of PATH in the class Konst = `C:\Users\myname`

The value of Konst.PATH in the class ConfigLoader = `C:\Users\myname/Documents/Hausaufgaben/`

The value of CONFIG_PATH = `C:\Users\myname/Documents/Hausaufgaben//Documents/Hausaufgaben/config.xml`

I never assign anything else to the constant (it shouldn't even editable duh) and I have no occurences of the words "Documents" or "Hausaufgaben" in the whole project.

Comment: you may want to google System properties and user.home

Comment: Are both using the same ClassLoader?

Answer (score 0):

Looks very strange as your path value as you are saying is

```
The value of PATH in the class Konst = C:\Users\myname
```

And value of `CONFIG_PATH` is

```
C:\Users\myname/Documents/Hausaufgaben//Documents/Hausaufgaben/config.xml
```

it should not change value of Konst.PATH Unless `Konst.PATH` in you ConfigLoader is different class it self.

Can you put some constant string for your Konst.PATH and check with that if you CONFIG_PATH changing based on that. if not then its using some other class.

```
public static final String PATH = "SOME/PATH/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah damn, I feel stupid now. Since this is a Maven project and the class Konst is in a different module then the rest, all I had to do was to clean install the module too, which I forgot. Thanks for the the help though.